# create() method override in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

class Sell(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    vat = models.IntegerField()
```

## serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class SellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sell
        fields = '__all__'
```

And after serializers and views I get that when i browse to input sell.

1. How do I automatically connect Customer object to Sell so that I dont need to select the customers objects? Using token or any idea?
2. Also how to override create() method on customer serializer to add products details from customer view?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass customer to the sell serializer automaticaly. You can pass it to the serializer's [save method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) in the view:

```
serializer.save(customer=request.user)
```

You need to exclude `customer` field from serializer:

```
class SellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sell
        exclude = ('customer',)
```

To save nested `product` you can save all new products to the list and then pass this list to the `product.add()` method:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        customer = Custome.objects.create(**validated_data)
        product_lits = [] 
        for product_details in product_data:                    
            product_list.append(Product.objects.create(**product_details))
        customer.product.add(*product_list)
        return customer
```